# asyncio to await a func that calls an API and returns a list of objects

Tags: python, asynchronous, session, python-asyncio

So, I have the following code:

```
def some_func(i):
   some_list_of_objs = call_some_API(param=i)
   return some_list_of_objs

def get_tasks(session):
   tasks = []
   for i in some_list_of_params:
       tasks.append(session.get(some_func(i)))
   return tasks

async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.extend(await response)
```

Now, when I run:

```
results = []    
await foo()
```

Program is giving a

```
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
```

I think issue lies in this line of code -

```
tasks.append(session.get(some_func(i)))
```

Can session.get only be used to call urls? If so, how do I call my function with session? I want to call my function, not any url.

Comment: `session.get` makes a GET request to a URL, `session.POST` makes a POST request, etc. If you want `call_some_API` to use your session, just pass it as an argument. You’ll make to use `async def` when you define `call_some_API`.

Comment: Can't follow. How do I pass call_some_API as an argument? call_some_API is not a function, the function is some_func()

Comment: You can’t pass a function to `session.get`. You can pass it the return value of a function. But whatever you pass it, it has to be a string containing the URL to which you want to make the GET request.

Comment: Instead of focusing on the implementation, let’s focus on the problem. Are you trying to figure out how to request multiple URLs at once?

Comment: some_func() has a lot of calculations going inside it apart from calling the urls. for e.g. counting the quota usage everytime the api is called, a while loop for fetching a particular resource since a single call to that resource only returns the first 50 values, etc. That's why I need to asynchronously run some_func()

Comment: would appreciate if you could let me know what I need to replace the "tasks.append(session.get(some_func(i)))" with? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you should be calling `session.get` inside `some_func` then.